# getting a "NSOrderedSetArrayProxy was mutated while being enumerated" error without mutation

Tags: ios, objective-c, exception, block, enumeration

I have two functions:

one that returns an array that is filled in a block

```
- (NSArray *)getArray {
    NSArray *someValues = @[@0, @42, @23, @5, @8, @2013];
    NSArray *filter = @[@42, @23, @5];

    //replacing this NSMutableOrderedSet with a NSMutableArray
    //and return just matched then, resolves the problem.
    //so the exception has to do something with that set.
    NSMutableOrderedSet *matched = [[NSMutableOrderedSet alloc] init];

    for (id value in someValues) {
        [filter enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
            if ([obj isEqual:value])
                [matched addObject:value];
        }];
    }
    return [matched array];
}
```

and another one that enumerates the returned array from the first method

```
- (void)enumArray:(NSArray *)array {
    NSEnumerator *enumerator = [array objectEnumerator];
    for (id obj in enumerator) {
        if ([obj isEqual:@42])
            [enumerator nextObject]; // <== this line causes the error!
    }
}
```

If i now do something like that

```
NSArray *array = [foo getArray];
[foo enumArray:array];
```

i will get a NSGenericException with following message:

> Collection <__NSOrderedSetArrayProxy: 0x123456> was mutated while
>   being enumerated

where the hell is something mutated. i don't get it. returning a copy from that array solves the problem, but i still don't get it.

The error has do something with the NSMutableOrderedSet, if i replace the set with an array i don't get an exception.

some screenshots, of exception thrown

[image: all exceptions breakpoint]
[image: crash]

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with that loop or with that line?

Comment: which one? thats just simplified code.

Comment: The one that causes the error. Why are you trying to advance the enumerator?

Comment: i use this to get next (or previous with reverse enumerator) object of an array base on a property, example is missing a break, just tried to reproduce the error with simple objects

Comment: Well, for one thing, the code you posted _doesn't_ throw an exception, so a) you should post some that exhibits the problem, and b) there might be another way to do what you want to do to get around the problem.

Comment: you don't get an exception? i added some screenshot of the exception thrown

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using *fast enumeration* while altering an enumerator instance.

Basically it is a big no-no to modify an object that you fast enumerate over (that form of the for loop you are using uses fast enumeration).  However, you use `[enumerator nextObject];` to access the next object from the enumerator, but this *modifies* the enumerator by removing the current object from it. So it is your use of nextObject *within* a `for...in` loop that is mutating the enumerator.

Get past this problem quickly by using a while loop instead of the for loop, a bit like this:

```
- (void)enumArray:(NSArray *)array {
    NSEnumerator *enumerator = [array objectEnumerator];
    while ((id obj = [enumerator nextObject])) {
        if ([obj isEqual:@42])
            [enumerator nextObject]; 
    }
}
```

This should get past the fast enumeration/mutation problem. Note, I have absolutely no idea why you want to move the enumerator on a step when obj is equal to 42, but am presuming within the context of the entire code-base that this makes sense!

Comment: can you also explain me why returning a copy of the array in the getArray function fixes that problem to?

Comment: Other than you are mixing and matching NSEnumerator and fast enumeration in the same loop, and you don't know how Apple have implemented them under the hood. See [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/Collections/Articles/Enumerators.html) for a more detailed discussion.

Comment: And in which this may be appropriate: `It is not safe to remove, replace, or add to a mutable collection’s elements while enumerating through it. If you need to modify a collection during enumeration, you can either make a copy of the collection and enumerate using the copy or collect the information you require during the enumeration and apply the changes afterwards.`

Answer (score 0):

The basic reason is, you can't edit/modify a mutable array while you're going through it.

So here are the two solutions,

1.Please use **`@synchronized()`** directive to lock the array while you mutate it.

```
- (void)enumArray:(NSArray *)array {

    NSEnumerator *enumerator = [array objectEnumerator];
    for (id obj in enumerator)
    {
        if ([obj isEqual:@42])
        {
            @synchronized(enumerator)
            {
              [enumerator nextObject]; // <== this line causes the error!
            }
        }
    }
}
```

2.Just do a **`copy`** of you NSArray and use it

```
- (void)enumArray:(NSArray *)array {

    NSEnumerator *enumerator = [[array copy] objectEnumerator];

    for (id obj in enumerator)
    {
        if ([obj isEqual:@42])
        {
          [enumerator nextObject]; // <== this line causes the error!
        }
    }
}
```